# Xcode iPad Rotation Problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, rotation, autorotate

I Have a Problem with my app I uploaded to the appstore. It was rejected because it didn't support both "Home-Button up" and "Home-Button down" orientations. Just Up. Now I try to fix that problem and need your help. I actually just have a webview and two toolbars with buttons. How can I make them rotate?

Comment: How is this related to Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

Add support for all orientations inside your view controllers:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

On the iPad it really does not make sense to say that app cannot be orientated with home button down but not with home button up.

Answer (score 0):

In the ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
      return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: I put the code into my AppDelegate.m and run it with the iPhone Simulator but when I rotate the simulator nothing is happening the app is not rotating its just the wrong way round... what's wrong?